# How to properly import svg as a VueComponent

Tags: svg, import, vue-component, vuejs3

I have an SVG that I intend to import as a VueComponent in my component from an icons directory,

here is the icons index.ts file:

```
import { VueComponent as Spinner } from './spinner.svg'

export { Spinner }
```

here is how I'm importing the Spinner SVG:

```
import { Spinner } from '../assets/icons'

export default defineComponent({
  components: { Spinner },
  setup () {}
})
```

I get an error saying the requested module does not provide an export named VueComponent as shown below. How do I solve this

[image: I get an error saying the requested module does not provide an export named VueComponent]

Answer (score 2):

Should be able to do it with `vue-svg-loader`

Install the loader

```sh
npm i -D vue-svg-loader@beta
```

create a `vue.config.js` file in project with:

```js
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: (config) => {
    const svgRule = config.module.rule('svg');

    svgRule.uses.clear();

    svgRule
      .use('vue-loader-v16')
      .loader('vue-loader-v16')
      .end()
      .use('vue-svg-loader')
      .loader('vue-svg-loader');
  },
};
```

MySvgComponent.js

```js
import MySvgFile from "../assets/mySvgFile.svg";
export { MySvgFile };
```

and then use...

```
<script>
import {MySvgFile} from "./components/MySvgComponent";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    MySvgFile
  }
};
</script>
```

Just note that the svg definitions may not work

you can try [this](https://github.com/visualfanatic/vue-svg-loader/issues/136#issuecomment-724205887) definition though

```
declare module '*.svg' {
    import type { DefineComponent } from 'vue';
    const component: DefineComponent;
    export default component;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to create a Vue component for each icon. For example,
`AddIcon.vue` is an icon with a + sign.
File content:

```
<template>
  <g>
    <rect
      id="Rectangle_1"
      data-name="Rectangle 1"
      width="100"
      height="22"
      rx="4"
      transform="translate(0 39)"
      fill="currentColor"
    />
    <rect
      id="Rectangle_2"
      data-name="Rectangle 2"
      width="100"
      height="22"
      rx="4"
      transform="translate(61) rotate(90)"
      fill="currentColor"
    />
  </g>
</template>
```

Then you can import the icon into the parent component just like any vue component.
`import AddIcon from "@/components/icons/AddIcon.vue"`
then register the icon inside components

```
components: {
...
AddIcon,
...
}
```

And use it inside the template of the parent component such as:

```
<template>
   <div>
     <svg>
       <add-icon />
     </svg>
   </div>
</template>
```